# How to get multisite wordpress blog's custom fields rss feed

Tags: rss, wordpress

I have multisite Wordpress blog that have three custom fields that have text heading for micro blog and two image fields. I want to get these are also in rss feed. I have tried [this stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333228/custom-fields-in-wordpress-rss-feed) post but it did not work for me.  Is there any specific plugin for multisites or how could I do that? Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to make an completely new RSS.
Just make a theme template: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates

Just paste the code from the original RSS feed in `/wp-includes/feed-rss.php`
And edit those loops.

After that make a page and assign it this newly created template.